# Unable to iterate the response body and manipulate/filter the response object using node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-request

I have below code which is going to invoke REST endpoint and return response back. I just tried to print the response.body in the console and It works perfectly fine.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var PORT = 8001;
 var request = require('request');
 var HashMap = require('hashmap');

   var endPoint="http://sandbox.dev.amazon.com/idsearch/environment/amazon/";

   app.get('/productId/:proId',async (req,res) => {  
     try
     {
          var headers ={
              "accept":"application/json"
          }

          var options = {
             url:endPoint.concat(req.params.proId),
             headers:headers
          }

          request(options, (error,response,body)=> {
          console.log(response.body)  // It returned response as below output JSON file
          res.send("STATUS CODE : 200");

        });

     }
     catch(error)
     {
        throw error;
     }
  });
```

Output:

```
{
    "<Some dynamic Content>": {
        "type": "PROD-ID",
        "environment": "amazon",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "EC-6S0005704A8324S98020",
                "source": "amazonstage2ma_paymentapiplatserv#TOKEN",
                "flags": [
                    "FLAG_DYNAMIC_VALUE",
                    "FLAG_ID_LOOKUP_SUPPORTED"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "callSummary": [
            {
                "pool": "slingshotrouter",
                "machine": "stage21007",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "0",
                "duration": 13400.0,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-942342192424j2j234"
            },
            {
                "pool": "slingshot",
                "machine": "stage21029",
                "apiName": "GET",
                "status": "1",
                "duration": 13368.0,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j234"
            },


            {
                "pool": "devstage_userbridgedomainserv",
                "machine": "amazon1int-g_userbridgedomainserv_22",
                "apiName": "POST",
                "status": "1",
                "duration": 15.0,
                "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424j2j290"
            }

        ],
        "partial": false
    }
}
```

The above output contains all the responses with respective Endpoint URL which is expected. But I just want to fetch only the object contains "Status: 1". I'm just wondering that How can I manipulate the response.body object to get the below JSON as output.

Expected Output:

```
 {
  "callSummary":[

              {
                    "pool": "slingshot",
                    "machine": "stage21029",
                    "apiName": "GET",
                    "status": "1",
                    "duration": 13368.0,
                    "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-12342342i842424j2j234"
              },

              {
                    "pool": "devstage_userbridgedomainserv",
                    "machine": "amazon1int-g_userbridgedomainserv_22",
                    "apiName": "POST",
                    "status": "1",
                    "duration": 15.0,
                    "link": "https://www.amazon.qa.pilot.com/Tid-02341723424i842424j2j290"
               }

             ]
        }
```

I just want to iterate the response.body obj and check the status as 1 if it's then I need to fetch all the details and form it as above payload. This is dynamic content but the template format is static.

I tried the below code to iterate the response.body but no luck.

```
    var string = JSON.stringify(response.body);
    var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
    var obj = objectValue.callSummary;
    console.log(obj.length);  // It returned undefined.
```

Please lead me to achieve this.

Comment: Your problem is that `callSummary` is not a top-level key in the JSON object in the body. "<Some dynamic Content>" is. You need to access `objectValue["<Some dynamic Content>"].callSummary`

Comment: It didnt work. I tried it returned undefinied.

Answer (score 0):

To return that json, just

```
res.json(response.body['<Some dynamic Content>'].callSummary);
```

Adding some validation and error handling would be a good idea before sending the response.

In case your key is just an example and you never know your first key value, **and** you always want the values of the first key

```
res.json(Object.values(response.body)[0].callSummary);
```

`Object.values` returns an array, so you can iterate the values if you want manage more than the first one

Comment: console.log(response.body['61705d3f91330'].callSummary);
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'callSummary' of undefined

Comment: When I use the let value = Object.value(response.body)[0].callsummary.length;  returned undefinied.

Comment: How can I iterate the JSON element ? can you please help me on this?

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => console.log(key, value)
);`
You also may are missing this header on your request `'content-type': 'application/json'`